# Matlab Simulink and Reinforcement Learning Approach

Tags: matlab, simulink, reinforcement-learning

I would like to create a project using a Matlab simulink environment model to find optimal parameters using reinforcement learning. Is it possible to export the environment data from matlab simulink and incorporate it into a python script or to create an interface to matlab simulink in order to train interactively with it? Or is there a better approach?

Unfortunately, this is rather vague, so I'm sorry, as I do not know what the matlab model will look like. It would also be helpful for me to see an example project or something along the lines of accessing Matlab Simulink data and reinforcement learning.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To create an interface with python script and the Simulink simulation, you can use [MATLAB Engine for Python](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html).

I could find a sample implementation in [this blog](https://medium.com/@soutrikbandyopadhyay/controlling-a-simulink-model-by-a-python-controller-2b67bde744ee). You can extend the *simulate* function in this example with an RL Agent to determine an action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simulink and generate coder from simulink. You must download simulink coder, matlab coder packages to generate code.